# Comparing the lengths of lists with list comprehension Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, boolean, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list comprehension function that checks the length of each lists `val..val6`  within the nested list functions `storage..storage4` to see if all the lists values lengths are greater than 0. Then returns a bool value if satisfies. So in `storage` `val2` has a length greater than 0 and so do all the other lists except for `val`, since not all the lists in `storage` have a length greater than 0 it will output `False`. `storage4` satisfies the condition where all the lists lengths are greater than 0 so it outputs `True`. How would I be able to modify the code to get the expected output?

```
val = []
val2 = [12,456,786,9]
val3 = [556]
val4 = [66,7,4,3,12]
val5 = [99,88,6]
val6 = [12,4567]

storage = [val,val2,val3]
storage2 = [val,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6]
storage3 = [val,val2,val4,val6]
storage4 = [val2,val5,val6]

def checking(list_val):
  newlist = [True for x in list_val if len(x) > 0]

print(checking(storage))
print(checking(storage2))
print(checking(storage3))
print(checking(storage4))
```

Output

```
None
None
None
None
```

Expected Output:

```
False
False 
False 
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting None because your function didn't return anything. Even if you return `newlist`, it will still not work as `newlist` is a list containing either True values or empty.

This can be done like below with help of `all()` and a generator expression -

```
def checking(list_val):
  return all(len(x) > 0 for x in list_val)
```

Here the generator expression will loop over all element in `list_val` and checks whether the length of the element is greater than 0. `all()` will check if all the elements produced by generator is True or not.

Another approach would be as @Lumorti mentioned, is to loop over and check if any sublist length is 0 and return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer cant believe I forgot to return it thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't even need that much code. Since an empty list will be `False`-y, you can just write `def checking(list_val): return all(list_val)`.  Also, the `all` and `any` functions will themselves break out of the loop  immediately (in the case of finding a single `False` value in the case of `all`, and in the case of finding a single `True` value with `any`) so this method is just as fast as manually looping over the list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the reason it's giving "None" is because you need a return statement in the function, currently the function doesn't return anything.

Here's an implementation that works, although it doesn't use a list comprehension since those are more for creating new lists rather than a single output:

```
val = []
val2 = [12,456,786,9]
val3 = [556]
val4 = [66,7,4,3,12]
val5 = [99,88,6]
val6 = [12,4567]

storage = [val,val2,val3]
storage2 = [val,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6]
storage3 = [val,val2,val4,val6]
storage4 = [val2,val5,val6]

def checking(list_val):
  for x in list_val:
      if len(x) == 0:
          return False
  return True

print(checking(storage))
print(checking(storage2))
print(checking(storage3))
print(checking(storage4))
```

Here it checks each element, if the length of the element is zero then it stops and returns False, otherwise it eventually returns True once it has checked everything.